# Convert string tenor to year

Tags: kdb

I have the following tenors in string (converted to symbols below) coming from a swap curve:

`` tenors_str : `1d`6m`1y`1y6m`2y`2y6m`3y`3y6m`4y`4y6m`5y`10y`20y`30y6m ``

I would like to create a function to parse those tenors and get the corresponding time in years.

For instance:

- `1d` should be 1/365.25
- `6m` should be 0.5
- `1y` should be 1.0
- `1y6m` should be 1.5
- `10y` should be 10.0

I have started by creating a dictionary like this:

`` tenor_to_year:`d`m`y!(1%365.25;1%12;1f); ``

But then I can't handle the case when there are more than 1 digit preceding the char `d`, `m` or `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach covers your use-cases:

```
f:{sum prd each 2 cut d[`$c]^"F"$c:cut[0,where b|prev b:x in raze string key d:tenor_to_year;x]};

q)f each string tenors_str
0.002737851 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 10 20 30.5
```